# How to get plugins that depends on a certain plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

various Jenkins modules were deprecated the past few weeks. While I could uninstall most of them I'm unable to remove [multiple-scms](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multiple-scms/) plugin, since some other plugin(s) seem to require it.

I was unable get a list of plugins that require multiple-scms through the plugin page search.

So is there any way to get a list of plugins that have a dependency on a certain plugin in Jenkins? Maybe with the help of a Groovy script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via script console:

```
println Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.getPlugin("multiple-scms").getDependents()
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the picture [image: dependencies]

or use the link https://plugins.jenkins.io/multiple-scms/#dependencies

Comment: Yeah this shows me the dependencies of that plugin. What I've needed was a list of plugins that depend on a given plugin, without checking all plugins manually.